# How do I hide one div and change the size of another div in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to click a particular link, which will then hide my sidebar `<section>` and resize the content `<section>`.  Currently I have the hiding mechanism working, however I'm struggling with the resizing part.

My code is currently as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sidebar-toggle-link').click(function() {
                $('#container-sidebar').toggle('slide');
        });
});
```

I've tried adding this within the second function:

```
var toggle_width = $('#container-content').width() == 100 ? '74%' : '100%';
$('#container-content').animate({ width: toggle_width });
```

This however scales the content `<section>` to 100%, but not back again when the link is clicked a second time - the sidebar reappears, but the content `<section>` gets shifted to below the sidebar, still at 100% size.

How do I do this in JQuery?

Comment: Please do not put `(Solved)` in the title header when your problem is solved. That's what the 'accept' checkmark is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var toggle_width = $('#container-content').width() == $(window).width() ? '74%' : '100%';
```

window or any parent wich 100% width is targeting.

You could try this too, depending style applied to your element (e.g padding, margin)

```
$('#container-content').outerWidth() == ...
```